# wget a website to csv

Tags: linux, wget

is there a way to `wget` a website and put it's tabular content in `.csv`?

or maybe a `cURL` request a webpage, grab it's tabular content represented in numbers that consists of HTML to `.csv`?

Comment: What do you mean by tabular content and what exact format do you think could represent an HTML page?

Comment: I want to grab this data from this website: http://currency.poe.trade/search?league=Prophecy&online=x&want=1&have=4 the content happens to sit on divs

Comment: could you use something like ` cat `wget www.something.com >> html.csv` `
(Notice backticks before wget and after .csv are part of command, not block code)

Comment: @MBayley I issued the command but I got the following erros:  sudo `cat wget http://currency.poe.trade/search?league=Prophecy&online=x&want=1&have=4 >> html.csv`
cat: wget: No such file or directory. I have the backticks over the command, it's not showing up on here.

Comment: I got the following error: Resolving currency.poe.trade (currency.poe.trade)... 104.18.51.127, 104.18.50.127
Connecting to currency.poe.trade (currency.poe.trade)|104.18.51.127|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Cookie coming from currency.poe.trade attempted to set domain to poe.trade
2016-07-07 05:43:03 ERROR 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Comment: `wget 'http://currency.poe.trade/search?league=Prophecy&online=x&want=1&have=4'` works but obviously will be in HTML, not CSV, then you can do some data extraction if you want but it can not realistically be done in a shell script.  You'd need to use HTML parsing libraries to make something that makes sense such as those available in Python, PHP, Perl, etc.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier, that worked! ty.

Comment: @MBayley You can escape embedded backticks to prevent it from messing up your code block. `cat \`wget www.something.com\` >> html.csv `. But the use of command sub and cat here is pointless anyway.

Comment: @123 thanks for the heads up. The idea was to cat the output of "wget" though I think assigning it a variable first then catting it would be a better way, but would require a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a class [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) that you can use to retrieve and parse html.

this code will fetch and extract the rows from the webpage. There is still more work necessary to extract the specific items you want but if you are willing to learn some PHP this will get you started

```php
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://currency.poe.trade/search?league=Prophecy&online=x&want=1&have=4');

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$rows = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "row")]'); //instance of DOMNodeList
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // var_dump($row);
    echo "Found {$row->nodeValue}";
}
```

You can run the code above by copying and pasting [in this online PHP interpreter](http://www.runphponline.com/)
When I run it I get the following sample output (truncated)

> Found Currency market // Prophecy ← go to item trades Protip Arrows always point from what you pay to what you get. (You get ⇐ You pay) Currency search Manage your shop Show search form League ProphecyHardcore ProphecyStandardHardcore Online only Off On What do you want? What do you have? Reset .... [more output]

once you've extracted the info you want then its pretty simple to just make each item of interest delimited by a `,` then insert and newline for each record and then you'll have a CSV file.

Note: for debugging you will need to dump a DOMelement in its HTML/XML markup format. You can use this:

> $xml = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($domElement);

or alternatively

> $html = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML($domElement);

more background at:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php